# openstack yoga volume creation fails

Tags: openstack, rabbitmq, cinder

We are trying to create cinder volume. Cinder API accepts the request, but volumes are stuck in `creating` state. This happens regardless of the backend used (i.e. also with `lvm`). Seems like some timeouts happening between cinder api and the rest of the processes. How to resolve this? Any leads are highly appreciated.

Here’s an excerpt from cinder-api logs:

> ```
> req-00001bfc-808d-4525-904d-207e40ac1e2d
> 9c8f8ded6e5947278acc0e5f10d0c7bf 949326f6d40c4d49a93fffac8b958b49 - -
> default default] POST
> http://10.10.1.83:8776/v3/949326f6d40c4d49a93fffac8b958b49/volumes
> 2022-08-11 17:17:01.415 21 INFO cinder.api.v3.volumes [None
> req-00001bfc-808d-4525-904d-207e40ac1e2d
> 9c8f8ded6e5947278acc0e5f10d0c7bf 949326f6d40c4d49a93fffac8b958b49 - -
> default default] Create volume of 4 GB 2022-08-11 17:17:01.435 21 INFO
> cinder.volume.api [None req-00001bfc-808d-4525-904d-207e40ac1e2d
> 9c8f8ded6e5947278acc0e5f10d0c7bf 949326f6d40c4d49a93fffac8b958b49 - -
> default default] Availability Zones retrieved successfully. 2022-08-11
> 17:17:01.619 21 INFO cinder.volume.api [None
> req-00001bfc-808d-4525-904d-207e40ac1e2d
> 9c8f8ded6e5947278acc0e5f10d0c7bf 949326f6d40c4d49a93fffac8b958b49 - -
> default default] Create volume request issued successfully. 2022-08-11
> 17:17:01.620 21 INFO cinder.api.openstack.wsgi [None
> req-00001bfc-808d-4525-904d-207e40ac1e2d
> 9c8f8ded6e5947278acc0e5f10d0c7bf 949326f6d40c4d49a93fffac8b958b49 - -
> default default]
> http://10.10.1.83:8776/v3/949326f6d40c4d49a93fffac8b958b49/volumes
> returned with HTTP 202 2022-08-11 17:17:11.119 23 INFO
> cinder.api.openstack.wsgi [None
> req-a50d2c2f-784b-481e-a34a-48f34225eed2 - - - - - -] GET
> http://10.10.1.80:8776/ 2022-08-11 17:17:11.120 23 INFO
> cinder.api.openstack.wsgi [None
> req-a50d2c2f-784b-481e-a34a-48f34225eed2 - - - - - -]
> http://10.10.1.80:8776/ returned with HTTP 300 2022-08-11 17:17:26.317
> 19 INFO cinder.api.openstack.wsgi [None
> req-5ffc061d-f253-45fa-ad32-5d3bb3f2274a
> 9c8f8ded6e5947278acc0e5f10d0c7bf 949326f6d40c4d49a93fffac8b958b49 - -
> default default] GET
> http://10.10.1.83:8776/v3/949326f6d40c4d49a93fffac8b958b49/volumes/detail?all_tenants=1&name=test1
> 2022-08-11 17:17:26.341 19 INFO cinder.volume.api [None
> req-5ffc061d-f253-45fa-ad32-5d3bb3f2274a
> 9c8f8ded6e5947278acc0e5f10d0c7bf 949326f6d40c4d49a93fffac8b958b49 - -
> default default] Get all volumes completed successfully. 2022-08-11
> 17:17:26.354 19 INFO cinder.api.openstack.wsgi [None
> req-5ffc061d-f253-45fa-ad32-5d3bb3f2274a
> 9c8f8ded6e5947278acc0e5f10d0c7bf 949326f6d40c4d49a93fffac8b958b49 - -
> default default]
> http://10.10.1.83:8776/v3/949326f6d40c4d49a93fffac8b958b49/volumes/detail?all_tenants=1&name=test1
> returned with HTTP 200 2022-08-11 17:17:28.081 21 INFO
> cinder.api.openstack.wsgi [None
> req-a2a433a3-50e6-4f2f-923b-21b0251338ca
> 9c8f8ded6e5947278acc0e5f10d0c7bf 949326f6d40c4d49a93fffac8b958b49 - -
> default default] GET
> http://10.10.1.83:8776/v3/949326f6d40c4d49a93fffac8b958b49/scheduler-stats/get_pools?detail=true
> 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault [None
> req-8ffc0660-49a5-4533-a60d-b4494d039203
> 9c8f8ded6e5947278acc0e5f10d0c7bf 949326f6d40c4d49a93fffac8b958b49 - -
> default default] Caught error: <class
> 'oslo_messaging.exceptions.MessagingTimeout'> Timed out waiting for a
> reply to message ID 56b3bf40bf824e1085283682367d1793:
> oslo_messaging.exceptions.MessagingTimeout: Timed out waiting for a
> reply to message ID 56b3bf40bf824e1085283682367d1793 2022-08-11
> 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault Traceback (most
> recent call last): 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py",
> line 441, in get 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  return
> self._queues[msg_id].get(block=True, timeout=timeout) 2022-08-11
> 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.10/queue.py", line 179, in get 2022-08-11
> 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault  raise Empty
> 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault
> _queue.Empty 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault During handling of the above exception,
> another exception occurred: 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault Traceback (most recent call last):
> 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cinder/api/middleware/fault.py",
> line 84, in __call__ 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  return req.get_response(self.application)
> 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webob/request.py",
> line 1313, in send 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  status, headers, app_iter =
> self.call_application( 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webob/request.py",
> line 1278, in call_application 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  app_iter = application(self.environ,
> start_response) 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webob/dec.py", line
> 143, in __call__ 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  return resp(environ, start_response)
> 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webob/dec.py", line
> 129, in __call__ 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  resp = self.call_func(req, *args, **kw)
> 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webob/dec.py", line
> 193, in call_func 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  return self.func(req, *args, **kwargs)
> 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/osprofiler/web.py",
> line 111, in __call__ 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  return
> request.get_response(self.application) 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22
> ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webob/request.py",
> line 1313, in send 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  status, headers, app_iter =
> self.call_application( 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webob/request.py",
> line 1278, in call_application 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  app_iter = application(self.environ,
> start_response) 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webob/dec.py", line
> 129, in __call__ 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  resp = self.call_func(req, *args, **kw)
> 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webob/dec.py", line
> 193, in call_func 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  return self.func(req, *args, **kwargs)
> 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keystonemiddleware/auth_token/__init__.py",
> line 341, in __call__ 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  response = req.get_response(self._app)
> 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webob/request.py",
> line 1313, in send 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  status, headers, app_iter =
> self.call_application( 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webob/request.py",
> line 1278, in call_application 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  app_iter = application(self.environ,
> start_response) 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webob/dec.py", line
> 143, in __call__ 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  return resp(environ, start_response)
> 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webob/dec.py", line
> 143, in __call__ 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  return resp(environ, start_response)
> 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/routes/middleware.py",
> line 153, in __call__ 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  response = self.app(environ,
> start_response) 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webob/dec.py", line
> 143, in __call__ 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  return resp(environ, start_response)
> 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webob/dec.py", line
> 129, in __call__ 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  resp = self.call_func(req, *args, **kw)
> 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webob/dec.py", line
> 193, in call_func 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  return self.func(req, *args, **kwargs)
> 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cinder/api/openstack/wsgi.py",
> line 839, in __call__ 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  return self._process_stack(request,
> action, action_args, 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cinder/api/openstack/wsgi.py",
> line 900, in _process_stack 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  action_result = self.dispatch(meth,
> request, action_args) 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cinder/api/openstack/wsgi.py",
> line 995, in dispatch 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  return method(req=request, **action_args)
> 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cinder/api/contrib/scheduler_stats.py",
> line 60, in get_pools 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  pools =
> self.scheduler_api.get_pools(context, filters=filters) 2022-08-11
> 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cinder/scheduler/rpcapi.py",
> line 199, in get_pools 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  return cctxt.call(ctxt, 'get_pools',
> filters=filters) 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/client.py",
> line 189, in call 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  result = self.transport._send( 2022-08-11
> 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oslo_messaging/transport.py",
> line 123, in _send 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  return self._driver.send(target, ctxt,
> message, 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault 
> File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py",
> line 689, in send 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  return self._send(target, ctxt, message,
> wait_for_reply, timeout, 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py",
> line 678, in _send 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  result = self._waiter.wait(msg_id,
> timeout, 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault 
> File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py",
> line 567, in wait 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  message = self.waiters.get(msg_id,
> timeout=timeout) 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py",
> line 443, in get 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR
> cinder.api.middleware.fault  raise oslo_messaging.MessagingTimeout(
> 2022-08-11 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault
> oslo_messaging.exceptions.MessagingTimeout: Timed out waiting for a
> reply to message ID 56b3bf40bf824e1085283682367d1793 2022-08-11
> 17:17:28.359 22 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault 2022-08-11
> 17:17:28.362 22 INFO cinder.api.middleware.fault [None
> req-8ffc0660-49a5-4533-a60d-b4494d039203
> 9c8f8ded6e5947278acc0e5f10d0c7bf 949326f6d40c4d49a93fffac8b958b49 - -
> default default]
> http://10.10.1.83:8776/v3/949326f6d40c4d49a93fffac8b958b49/scheduler-stats/get_pools?detail=true
> returned with HTTP HTTPStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
> ```

Comment: You should check your rabbitmq logs, everything related to messaging points to rabbitmq. Does `openstack volume service list` show it as up?

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to reply.. I couldn't figure it out from the logs earlier , since we have less time we just restarted cinder and rabbitmq and that fixed the issue.

Comment: If restarting fixed it I suggest to look out for any traces pointing to resource bottlenecks, like max open files or something like that. IIRC we had an issue a while ago when we noticed rabbitmq interruptions and noticed we had notifications enabled but no consumer. After we disabled the notifications rabbit consumed way less resources and worked more stable. But as I wrote, there is some bottleneck which I recommend to find or you'll end up with a cronjob restarting services. ;-)

Comment: @eblock Thanks for your valuable suggestions. Will certainly look into it

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured **service tokens**?
"For all OpenStack releases after 2023-05-10, it is required that Nova be configured to send a service token to Cinder and Cinder to receive it"

*To prevent long-running job failures: If the chain of operations takes a long time, the user’s token may expire before the action is completed, leading to the failure of the user’s original request.
One way to deal with this is to set a long token life in Keystone, and this may be what you are currently doing. But this can be problematic for installations whose security policies prefer short user token lives. Beginning with the Queens release, an alternative solution is available. You have the ability to configure some services (particularly Nova and Cinder) to send a “service token” along with the user’s token. When properly configured, the Identity Service will validate an expired user token when it is accompanied by a valid service token. Thus if the user’s token expires somewhere during a long running chain of operations among various OpenStack services, the operations can continue.*

For more detail and instructions see [cinder documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/cinder/latest/configuration/block-storage/service-token.html)